# SNMP OID resolver

Tags: python, snmp, oid, resolver

I am writing Python code in which a user inputs a SNMP OID in any of the following forms:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.90.1.2
internet.2.1.90.1.2
```

I want my code to resolve `internet` to `1.3.6.1`.

I was thinking of creating a dictionary and giving the corresponding values to the object names but I don't think that's a good idea.

Please help me in guiding how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. NetSnmp provides a `snmptranslate` method - that may be useful starting point.

   Its man page says its purpose is to:

   > translate MIB OID names between numeric and textual forms.

   There are already Python bindings for `net-snmp` available, see [these SO questions](/search?q=python%20net-snmp).
2. Alternatively  [pysnmp](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/) provides similar. See SO question ["Translating pysnmp numerical oid output into symbolic names"](/q/7473467).